# SSIS 2019 - Derived Column String Date/Time MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS.s to datetime2

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm having a FlatFile of Call detailed record data (CDR) There are two columns containing a string date `MM/DD/YYYY` and a time column with the format `HH:MM:SS.s`. I would like to merge these two columns into a `datetime2` datatype, however, I'm not able to achieve my desired goal.

I have tried to stack two Derived Column ontop of each other with the first one converting the data format to `YYYY-MM-DD` using the following expression

`((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(((DT_DATE)[6]))) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + ((DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(((DT_DATE)[6]))),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + ((DT_WSTR,2)DAY(((DT_DATE)[6]))),2)`*

* MM/DD/YYYY is stored in [6]
* Validated outputs YYYY-MM-DD

Witin the second Derived Column I'm creating a column called `StartDateTime`

Exp: `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,1)((DT_WSTR,10)SDATE + (DT_WSTR,10)7)`

* SDATE comes from the first derive, 7 is time `HH:MM:SS.s`

Comment: If these are string values, you're better off not trying to convert it to a date first, and the date time data type, properly format the string first, and then convert, or (if the column in SQL Server is already a `datetime2(1)` get the value into the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.n` and SQL Server will aklways appropriately implicitly convert it.

Comment: @Larnu The intention of my first derived was just to format the string properly but still keeping it as a string format. I have posted an answer below with a solution that worked for me (for now; might not be the best solution, it's my first day in SSIS).

Comment: @PetterÖstergren, SSIS is super fussy converting to date.  SQL is much more forgiving.  You might consider loading this into a staging table and doing the datetime conversion afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a working pipeline, was mostly some CAST misinterpretations within my previous code.

Derived column one: `((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(((DT_DATE)[6]))) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + ((DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(((DT_DATE)[6]))),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + ((DT_WSTR,2)DAY(((DT_DATE)[6]))),2)`

Derived column two: `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,1)(SDATE + [7])`

Answer (score 0):

First try to concatenate these two columns using derived column (as you say both are string type) and then use data conversion task to convert the merged column to `T_DBTIMESTAMP2`